# map.addLayer(markerClusters) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I get this error:

> map.addLayer(markerClusters) is not a function

in for my markerClusters since I updated the following packages:

```
"leaflet": "^0.7.7",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^0.5.0",
"react-leaflet": "^0.12.3",
"react-leaflet-cluster-layer": "0.0.3",
"react-leaflet-control": "^1.1.0",
```

to

```
"leaflet": "^0.7.7",
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.0.3",
"react-leaflet": "^1.1.6",
"react-leaflet-control": "^1.4.0",
"react-leaflet-cluster-layer": "0.0.3",
```

I need this update for another map on my page, so I dont want to use the old versions. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this.

I just found that on SO that map is not a global variable, but as its defined, it is available. Googling also hasn't brought anything up, which is of use.

Thanks in Advance!

Here is my MarkerClusters.js file:

```
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import Leaflet from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';
import styles from './MarkerCluster.scss';
import markerDefaultIcon from '../../../assets/images/marker_default.png';

export default class MarkerCluster extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        map: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        features: PropTypes.array
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.createMarkerClusters(this.props);      
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.features !== this.props.features) {
            this.createMarkerClusters(nextProps);
        }
    }

    createMarkerClusters = (props = this.props) => {
        const { map, features } = props; 
        if (!features || !features.length) {
            return null;
        }
        const markerClusters = Leaflet.markerClusterGroup({
            disableClusteringAtZoom: 14,
            maxClusterRadius: 110,
            polygonOptions: {
                color: '#fff'
            },
            iconCreateFunction(cluster) {
                const count = cluster.getChildCount();
                let clusterSizeClassName = styles.small_cluster;
                if (count > 80) {
                    clusterSizeClassName = styles.large_cluster;
                } else if (count > 15) {
                    clusterSizeClassName = styles.mid_cluster;
                }
                return Leaflet.divIcon({ 
                    iconSize: [45, 45],
                    className: `${styles.marker_cluster} ${clusterSizeClassName}`,
                    html: `<b class="${styles.cluster_inner}"> ${count} </b>`
                });
            }
        });   
        const icon = Leaflet.divIcon({
            className: '',
            iconSize : [48, 64],
            iconAnchor: [9, 63],
            html: `<img class="${styles.marker}" src='${markerDefaultIcon}'/>`
        });
        features.forEach(feature => {
            const { geometry, properties } = feature;
            const title = properties.name;
            const { coordinates: [lng, lat] } = geometry;
            const marker = Leaflet.marker(new Leaflet.LatLng(lat, lng), { title, icon });
            marker.bindPopup(this.getPopupTemplate(properties));
            markerClusters.addLayer(marker);
        });
        map.addLayer(markerClusters);
        window.setTimeout(() => {            
            if (this.markerClusters) {
                map.removeLayer(this.markerClusters); 
            }
            this.markerClusters = markerClusters; 
        }, 300);
    }

    getPopupTemplate = props => {
        const createImageHolder = image => {
            if (!image) {
                return '';
            }
            return (
                `<div class="${styles.image}">
                    <img src="${props.image.medium}" />
                </div>`
            );
        }
        return (
            `<div class="${styles.popup}">
                <a 
                    class="${styles.link}"
                    href="/d/${props.id}"
                >
                    <div class="${styles.title}">${props.name}</div>
                    ${createImageHolder(props.image)}
                    Buy
                </a>
            </div>`
        )
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Stack trace:**

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: map.addLayer is not a function
>       at MarkerCluster._this.createMarkerClusters (MarkerCluster.js:64)
>       at MarkerCluster.componentWillReceiveProps (MarkerCluster.js:20)
>       at ReactCompositeComponent.js:611
>       at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.updateComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:610)
>       at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.receiveComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:547)
>       at Object.receiveComponent (ReactReconciler.js:125)
>       at Object.updateChildren (ReactChildReconciler.js:109)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._reconcilerUpdateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:208)
>       at ReactDOMComponent._updateChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:312)

Comment: Leaflet.markercluster 1.0+ is for Leaflet 1.0+

Comment: Does it seem that "map" was not passed (as props) correctly? Can you "console.log(map)" before addLayer to see if it has value?

Comment: @ghybs: i also tried the leaflet-0.7 branch. doesnt work also

Comment: @thinhvo0108 
log looks ok: 
`Map {props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater: Object, _leafletEvents: Object…}
bindContainer
:
function (container)
className
:
"Map__map___2OehO"
container
:
div#map.Map__map___2OehO.leaflet-container.leaflet-fade-anim
context
:
Object
leafletElement
:
NewClass
props
:
Object
refs
:
Object
state
:
null
updater
:
Object
_leafletEvents
:
Object
_reactInternalInstance
:
ReactCompositeComponentWrapper
isMounted
:
(...)
replaceState
:
(...)
__proto__
:
MapComponent`

Answer (score 1):

So we found the error:

we called the MarkerCluster object in our Map with:

```
                    <MarkerCluster
                        map={ this.refs.map }
                        features={ features } />
```

So as this.refs.map is the react-leaflet Map Object, which doesn't have the function addLayer(); 
This function is only in the original leafletElement.

so we use

`map.leafletElement.addLayer();`

instead of

```
map.addLayer();
```